# How to clear WSS_UsageApplication content?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, database

We've been using Sharepoint 2013. My question / problem is : The database is about 35 Gb and a shrink db on an SQL level didnt help. How to clear WSS_UsageApplication content?

Comment: Have you resolved this problema? I am in the same situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the retention period
[How-to...](http://blog.it-kb.ru/2015/03/31/sharepoint-server-2013-how-to-reduce-size-of-logging-database-wss_usageapplication-via-change-retention-period-and-run-usage-data-import-job-and-purge-old-data-with-shrink/)

Comment: Please add more details to this answer. Your answer should be stand-alone for the link (using the link only as a source and to more details)

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was 900GB with around 30 big dbo.**TaskUsage_PartitionXX** tables.

1- go to SSMS and by opening object Explorer (f7) of WSS_UsageApplication find the big tables which in most cases are TaskUsages

2- create a series of  truncate and run them

```
truncate TABLE [dbo].TaskUsage_PartitionXX
```

3- shrink your whole database to forexample 5% free space which takes around 4 minutes in my case for 900GB

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(N'WSS_UsageApplication', 5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=400: this link tells you how to set retention which will have a longer lasting effect and help you Shrink your DB (I was able to reclaim nearly 80% of the space consumed by WSS_UsageApplication